# How to send and retrieve data from asp by using the HttpURLConnection in Android?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, httpurlconnection

I have a login process in android, a user account information in a database and a aspx file which can check whether the username and password is correct or not.

In my aspx.cs file, I have a process method to check the username and password like this:

```
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    HttpRequest request = context.Request;
    HttpResponse response = context.Response;
    System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState session = context.Session;

    string result = "";

    try
    {

        string action = request.Form["action"].ToString();

        switch (action)
        {
           //Login test
            case "login":
                result = this.login(session, request);
                break;         
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        result = "{\"message\":\"" + e.Message + "\"}";
    }

    response.Clear();
    response.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8;";
    response.Write(result);
    response.End();
     }



#region Login test
 private string login(System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState session,      HttpRequest request)
     {
        LoginSample sample = new LoginSample();
       JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
   string username = request.Form["username"];
   string password = request.Form["password"];

   bool login = sample.Login(username, password);
   if (login)
       jo.Add("msg", "success");
   else
       jo.Add("msg", "failed");

   return jo.ToString();
```

}

And my class to pass the username and password to C# `INCOMPLETE`:

```
   public static String excutePost(String vUserName, String vPassword)
     {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("localhost:60068/SampleLogin.aspx");

        String urlParameters="param1=" + URLEncoder.encode(vUserName,"UTF-8")+
        "&param2="+URLEncoder.encode(vPassword,"UTF-8");

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(urlParameters.getBytes().length);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        dataOutputStream.flush();
        dataOutputStream.close();

        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        return response.toString();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

How can I pass the parameters to the aspx.cs file and process and return a boolean back to android? Please help.

Comment: You are already posting your parameters. So why do you ask? Instead of a boolean your script should return a text like 'succes' or 'failed'.

Comment: I have no idea how my urlParameters works and apply to the C#

Comment: But why aren't you telling if there is a connection? And or if there is a catch? And what you get back in response.toString()? YOU should tell us because how should we know alll that?

Comment: `new URL("localhost:60068/SampleLogin.aspx");`. You forgot to tell the protocol: `new URL("http://localhost:60068/SampleLogin.aspx");`. Moreover you cannot use localhost as host name. Please tell where your server is running and if you use an emulator or a device for Android.

Comment: In the C# code you can see that parameters login, username and password are expected. But in your Android code you send only param1 and param2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Http response code value after write data to outputstream.

```
//Write Data
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(conn.getResponseCode())
                   .append(" ")
                   .append(conn.getResponseMessage())
                   .append("\n");
// Read response data
```